# How can I protect an excel sheet, except for a particular cell using Open XML 2.0?

Tags: openxml-sdk

I am generating a report using OpenXML and exporting it to excel. I want to protect the excel sheet except for a particular cell.

If anyone has worked on this before, kindly help

Thanks,
Amolik

Answer (score 1):

```
PageMargins pageM = 
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<PageMargins>();
SheetProtection sheetProtection = new SheetProtection();
sheetProtection.Password = "CC";
sheetProtection.Sheet = true;
sheetProtection.Objects = true;
sheetProtection.Scenarios = true;
ProtectedRanges pRanges = new ProtectedRanges();
ProtectedRange pRange = new ProtectedRange();
ListValue<StringValue> lValue = new ListValue<StringValue>();
lValue.InnerText = "A1:E1"; //set cell which you want to make it editable
pRange.SequenceOfReferences = lValue;
pRange.Name = "not allow editing";
pRanges.Append(pRange);
worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertBefore(sheetProtection, pageM);
worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertBefore(pRanges, pageM);
```

ref : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6f7502d-3867-4d5b-83a9-b4e0e211068f/how-to-lock-specific-columns-in-xml-workbook-while-exporting-dataset-to-excel?forum=oxmlsdk

Comment: Good grief, unlike many openxml tips that actually works, thanks! Although just to make the code clearer I think you should change pRange.Name to "Allow editing" because that's what it does.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the OpenXML Productivity Toolkit?

from what I can see you have to add a

```
new CellFormat
```

with attribute

```
ApplyProtection = true
```

to

```
CellFormats
```

append

```
new Protection
```

with attribute

```
Locked = false
```

to the the `CellFormat` you created.

`CellFormat` is a element of `CellFormats` which is a element of `Stylesheet`

then to the `Worksheet` you add a

```
new SheetProtection(){ Password = "CC1A", Sheet = true, Objects = true, Scenarios = true };
```

I havent tried this, but it should be easy enought to find out what you need to do with the Productivity Toolkit. I hope this points you and anyone trying to do this in the right direction.